# Bearer token + identity.isAuthenticated

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identity, bearer-token

I am building a web application in MVC together with bearde tokens. Everything works very fine but I have a little question.

When I log in, I'm setting the access token in the session storage. And for every request I get the token. So far so good. The authorization works fine.

But when I close my computer, or after a few hours, I see that the sessionStorage is empty in my browser event though my web application says that identity.user.isAuthenticated is still true? How is this possible?

Or am I doing it wrong with setting the access token in my session storage?

I'm sorry that I havn't code examples but the code is protected.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The *sessionStorage* of your browser doesn't know if your autheticated or not. It just stores a bool value received from the server that says that in that concrete moment your are autheticated. However, the Authentication is made at server side, and only at server side will know if you are autheticated or not.

What you might store in *sessionStorage* is your token and refresh token. The token will be used on every request to validate your session. The refresh token will be used in case your token has expired.

In the situation that you commented, I'm pretty sure that even in your sessionStorage says that you are Authenticated, when you try to acess using your expired token, this will fail.

Comment: Ok, I understand that the sessionStorage is not responsible for the Authentication. But in my controller class I use the Authorize attribute and in my view (to show the correct menu item) I'm using user.identity.isAuthenticated. Now the situation is: sometimes the isAuthenticated returns true even if there is no access token in storage... How is this possible?

Comment: Are you using cookie autentication? I mean, maybe you are storing the token value in the browser cookie. So sessionStorage is useless because you are not using it.